How to effectively find all objects where ltree path have at least one value from array?
I have a query which is slow:
SELECT id
FROM t
WHERE path @
'id1|id2|id3' -- and more like this

So it finds all objects where ltree path have at least one value from list of ids, but it's slow, I already have indexes on given field but it still slow, how can I speed up the query? Maybe using different operator or approach?
I've tried other operators like ~, but it didn't work.

B-tree indexes won't help you here. Have you tried GIST indexes? If that is still too slow, then you will need a different design. Caching or something. Which heavily depends on what really you are trying to achieve.

I have GIST indexes.
